# is there a better way to order a IEnumerable to match an arbitrary ordering?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I came across this problem at work, and though I have a solution, I can't help feeling there is a more elegant way. The use of List.IndexOf() stands out as a bit hacky to me.

I have to sort a collection of BreakdownItems by credit rating. Credit ratings don't follow alphabetical order so I've treated them as just having some arbitrary, non logical order.

```
IEnumerable<BreakdownItem> unsortedCreditRatings = new List<BreakdownItem>
        {
            new BreakdownItem{ Name = "CCC", Weight=20d},
            new BreakdownItem{ Name = "AA", Weight=20d},
            new BreakdownItem{ Name = "AAA", Weight=10d},
            new BreakdownItem{ Name = "B", Weight=50d},
        };

        var sortOrder = new List<string> 
    { "AAA", "AA", "A", "BBB", "BB", "B", "CCC", "below CCC" };

        var sortedRatingBreakdown = unsortedCreditRatings
           .OrderBy(item => sortOrder.IndexOf(item.Name));
```

Comment: Having repeated strings like that for ratings opens the possibility of data integrity issues.  Have you considered an enum for your rating values instead?

Comment: there is an enum already, I'm not using it here because "below CCC" doesn't fit into the Enum. but the question is a more general point about the arbitrary ordering

Comment: So, anything below CCC you want to pool together in the same order?

Comment: Seeing both the answers, I think it's clear to me that I just need to add a private enum for this context, and ignore the existing enum that the rest of the system uses. In fact I've done that in the past for similar problems, I just forgot it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you make the credit rating an enum instead of a string?  You could then assign those enum values the correct sort order.

Answer (score 3):

As I alluded in my comment above, having the multiple credit ratings as a string can cause data integrity issues, I'd move those to an `enum` instead, such as:

```
public enum CreditRatings
{
     AAA,
     AA,
     A,
     BBB,
     BB,
     B,
     CCC,
     etc
}
```

And you instead store that in your `BreakdownItem`, you can do:

```
var sortedRatingBreakdown = unsortedCreditRatings.OrderBy(item => item.Rating);
```

If you **must** store them as a `string`, and can't use an `enum` you could consider using a `Dictionary<string, int>` or something like that to store your ordering so that you at least get O(1) lookup time:

```
var ratingOrders = new Dictionary<string,int>
    {
        { "AAA", 1 },
        { "AA", 2 },
        { "A", 3 },
        etc...
    };
```

Then you can order by the results of the dictionary:

```
var sortedRatingBreakdown = unsortedCreditRatings.OrderBy(item => ratingOrders[item.Name]);
```

Answer (score 2):

[Enumerable.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675.aspx) preserves the order of the first (or outer) sequence. If you are not keen on the enum approach, you can use this and without needing to do `OrderBy` explicitly.

```
var orderedRatings = from item in sortOrder
                     join rating in unsortedCreditRatings
                     on item equals rating.Name
                     select rating;
```